# Greek words are not displayed in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am opening a file(that was created from my professor) with Matlab (check image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbPAt.png)) or Octave but all greek words (comments section, print sections) are displayed in an unknown language?

Can anybody assist me on this ?

Comment: Your systems use different encodings. You have to set the encoding for the file.

Comment: If you open the file with say Notepad++ or even Microsoft Word, can you see letters correctly?

Comment: Please answer the question of User81862311

Comment: I cannot open with notepad, i tried many times , sorry for late reply

Comment: Try it with Microsoft Word. If you can't see the characters correctly in Microsoft Word, then I am not sure if it is even an encoding issue. But anyway, try changing your character set encoding by using [`slCharacterEncoding()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/slcharacterencoding.html) and setting it to different encodings to see if it changes anything?